# How can you unlock the Ragnarok coliseum "Take Their Hand" title/"Enemies Yesterday, Friends Today" achievement?

Tags: half-minute-hero-the-second-coming

One of the Half Minute Hero 2 titles requires completing the Ragnarok coliseum challenge. This is linked to this Steam achivement:

> [image]
>
> #### Enemies Yesterday, Friends Today
>
> Unlocked "Take Their Hand" title.

What do I need to do for this?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to complete all coliseums, all in Ragnarok:

1. Q61. The Battle Coliseum
2. The Battle Coliseum by Coliseum Village (which by the way holds an Angel Diary)
3. The Underground Coliseum north of Ungoo Village.
4. The Heaven Coliseum in the upstairs of Unrivaled Championship of the World, north of Contractu Village.
5. The Hell Coliseum north, also found there.

To unlock the last coliseum, you must defeat however defeat Cozain thrice. Apparently, it's a random encounter in these three places  and times:

1. Pharohzun Castle left of Barroco Village in Judgement.
2. Temple of Time north of Urchine Village in Revolution.
3. The Underground Colliseum north of Ungoo Village in Ragnarok.

Defeating Cozain for the fourth time in the Hell Coliseum awards you the Take Their Hand title and the Enemies Yesterday Friends Today achievement. (Additionally, Cozain joins your party.)

Comment: Many thanks to [this discussion](http://steamcommunity.com/app/240970/discussions/0/540738051323190123/) for filling in the holes.